# Jmeter => How to add a jmx file in the transaction controller

Tags: jmeter

Does anyone know how to import a jmx file into your transaction controller?

[My Load Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Ier.png)

Pretty simple question and I am sure its a simple answer.  Do you create a transaction controller first? Then soemhow import the jmx file?  My tutor added the first two but I wasn't paying attention now he is not available and need to finish this tonight

Help pls

Answer (score 0):

1. The test seems to be recorded via [BlazeMeter Chrome extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi) so I don't think your "tutor" has added anything.
2. [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-transaction-controller) doesn't add a lot of value, it's just a container which sums response times of its children [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), it can be added using context menu:

   [image]

   Samplers can be added to the Transaction Controller in exactly the same manner:

   [image]
3. If you need to include an external [.jmx script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) somewhere - take a look at [Include Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller)